# Django/Python: how can i filter with Model's custom method?? Is this possible?

Tags: python, django

I have a model with a custom method. Here's the example:

```
class MyModel(models)
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   nickname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   time_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

   def sample_method(self)
       right_now = datetime.now()
       created_time = self.time_created
       time2compare = timedelta(minutes=3)

       timeout = True
       if(right_now - created_time) > time2compare:
           timeout = False
       return timeout
```

What I'm trying to do is do something like this (i know this doesn't work)

queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(timeout=False)

How could i solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a custom method on your model for filtering, because the filters will be resolved to saw sql, which will not be possible with some python code. Nonetheless the following should solve your problem:

```
import datetime
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(\
     time_created__lt=(datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(minutes=3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your timeout test is very trivial to reimplement as a queryset filter.

For a really complex test that can't be expressed in Django query language or raw SQL, you can write something like:

```
def sample_filter(self, method_name, arg=False)
    for i in self.objects.all():
        if getattr(self, method_name)() == arg:
            yield i
```

This method will return an iterator to every instance x of the Model where x.method_name() == arg. However, this can't be chained like a queryset.